# "Нужно знать как." Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Нужно знать как.**

На мой взгляд, это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором придаточная  часть представлена союзным словом *как*.

[§ 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136)

> Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:....
>   если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): Я бы тоже желал знать почему (Л. Т.); Не знаю почему, но я его не понимал (Триф.); Трудно сказать почему; Он ушёл и не сказал куда; Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил когда; Мать определяла температуру ребёнка губами: приложит их ко лбу и сразу определит сколько; Кто-то подал больному чашку воды, он даже не взглянул кто; Я не скажу какое, я говорю — большое несчастье.